# Python: Print row name in csv with matching column contents using Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

So, I'm using pandas in Python. I'm reading in a csv that looks something like this:

```
imageName     color1     color2     color3     color4
img1          Red        Red        Red        Red
img2          Blue       Green      Red        Blue
img3          Yellow     Blue       Red        White
img4          Blue       Blue       Blue       Blue
```

What I'm wanting to to is print the rows(by image name) if color1, color2, color3, and color4 are all equal.
If I were to do it in SQL

```
SELECT: imageName 
FROM: rows 
WHERE: color1 == color2 == color3 == color4
```

would give me img1 and img4

I'm pretty new to Pandas and have been trying to work out the syntax but I keep running into issues.

What I'm trying right now is:

```
if (df[(df['color1'] == df['color2'] == df['color3'] == df['color4']])]
    print df['imageName']
```

But I'm running into errors no matter what I try.

I'm getting:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any(), or a.all().
```

But I'm struggling to figure out where to use those. Or If I'm even going about it the right way. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html): for a similarish-syntax:

```
>>> df.query("color1 == color2 == color3 == color4")
  imageName color1 color2 color3 color4
0      img1    Red    Red    Red    Red
3      img4   Blue   Blue   Blue   Blue
>>> df.query("color1 == color2 == color3 == color4").imageName
0    img1
3    img4
Name: imageName, dtype: object
```

Alternatively,you could index using a boolean Series:

```
>>> df[df.filter(like="color").apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis=1) == 1]
  imageName color1 color2 color3 color4
0      img1    Red    Red    Red    Red
3      img4   Blue   Blue   Blue   Blue
```

although this is subtly different, because `nunique` will ignore `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

This is one method, I'm trying to figure out a vectorised method, basically you define a function that takes your row and then call apply, passing the function name and param `axis=1` to apply row-wise. The color_cols is just a list of your color column names defined by: `color_cols = [col for col in df if 'color' in col]`

```
In [21]:

def all_equal(x):
    return x['color1'] == x['color2'] == x['color3'] == x['color4']

df[color_cols].apply(all_equal, axis=1)
Out[21]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
In [23]:

df[df[color_cols].apply(all_equal, axis=1)]['imageName']
Out[23]:
0    img1
3    img4
Name: imageName, dtype: object
```

A faster method would be to define a mask and using the bitwise operators:

```
In [27]:
# mask tests if color 1 equals color 2 and color 3 equals color 4 and color 1 equals color 3 if this is true then all must be the same value
mask = (df['color1'] == df['color2']) & (df['color3'] == df['color4']) & (df1['color1'] == df['color3'])
mask
Out[27]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
In [28]:

df[mask]['imageName']
Out[28]:
0    img1
3    img4
Name: imageName, dtype: object
```

**Timings**

```
In [29]:

%timeit df.query("color1 == color2 == color3 == color4").imageName
100 loops, best of 3: 7.24 ms per loop
In [30]:

%timeit df[(df['color1'] == df['color2']) & (df['color3'] == df['color4']) & (df1['color1'] == df['color3'])].imageName

100 loops, best of 3: 3.22 ms per loop
```

there is another method calling [`eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval):

```
In [39]:

%timeit df[df.eval("color1 == color2 & color3 == color4 & color1 == color3")].imageName
100 loops, best of 3: 7.53 ms per loop

In [40]:

%timeit df[df[color_cols].apply(all_equal, axis=1)].imageName
100 loops, best of 3: 2.55 ms per loop
```

The mask method is over 2x faster than the query and eval method for this sample dataset. The `apply` method is actually the fastest method but it will not scale as well as the other methods as this essentially loops over each row.

Comment: Unless you're *very* fast at typing, I think the mask method is still slower. :-)  More seriously, usually the `query` translation overhead means you don't start winning until arrays get pretty big (for me, on this problem, `df` needs to be ~1M rows long before `query` is faster.)

Comment: @DSM indeed this would get tiresome to type out, I was a little surprised that `eval` was a little slower than `query`